# Bash conditional validating the contents of two file lines

Tags: bash, if-statement, sed, conditional-statements

I'm attempting to verify that a particular file (SQL output from ij) has particular values on two given lines before proceeding.

My intention is to ensure that line 5 contains ----------- and line 6 contains 1

At the moment I am attempting:

```
if sed -n '5p' $SQLFILE == "-----------" && sed -n '6p' $SQLFILE == "1";
then
print "Success\n\n"
else
printf "Failure\n\n"
exit 200
fi
```

The above fails with "syntax error near -n"

Update:

Running with changes suggested (with -x set)

```
++ sed -n 5p ./testsql.txt
+ '[' ----------- == ----------- ']'
++ sed -n 6p ./testsql.txt
+ '[' '1          ' == 1 ']'
+ printf 'Initial Datasource Not Found, Or Error Running SQL Script. Exiting\n\n'
```

For reference:

```
[rvp@linuxtest UtilitiesTests]# sed -n '5p' $SQLFILE
-----------
[rvp@linuxtest UtilitiesTests]# sed -n '6p' $SQLFILE
1
```

Comment: BTW, `=` is more portable than `==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `$(...)` to get the output of the `sed` commands. Then use `test` or `[` to perform the equality test in `if`.

Use `-eq` to perform numeric comparison instead of string comparison. This will ignore the extra spaces on line 6.

```
if [ "$(sed -n '5p' "$SQLFILE")" = "-----------" ] && [ "$(sed -n '6p' "$SQLFILE")" -eq "1" ]
```

You should also remember to quote variables and command substitutions. And the portable equality operator is `=`, `==` is a bash extension.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and helpful response

When I modified as per above, the if still took the else path

Comment: That's unreadable, please add it to the question in a code block.

Comment: line 6 has a space after `1`. So change it to `== "1 "`

Comment: I've changed that from `==` to `-eq` so it will do a numeric comparison instead of string comparison. That will ignore the spaces.